# Python web.py error OperationalError: near "name": syntax error

Tags: python, web.py

I'm getting an error with the following code:

```
class SomePage:
    def GET(self,name):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('./DB/ershou.db')
        LjDB = conn.cursor()
        searcher = web.input()
        DBsearch = LjDB.execute("select * from caiji where post like '%%%s%%'"%(searcher))
        for ss in DBsearch:
            print ss[1],
            print ss[2]
        return searcher.name
```

This is the error I'm talking about:

```
OperationalError: near "name": syntax error
```

What is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use string interpolation, *especially* when taking input from the web! Learn the lesson [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) teaches and use SQL parameters:

```
DBsearch = LjDB.execute("select * from caiji where post like ?", 
                        ('%{}%'.format(searcher),))
```

This is safer, faster, and more flexible.